# Firebase customtoken incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Building and ios chat application. Started testing generated a token but when it is passed as customtoken ios throwing error.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyeHAiOjE0ODM4NzEyOTAsInYiOjAsImQiOnsidWlkIjoiNTg0MTVhM2ZkOTA1MGVjZjAzOGI0NWU3In0sImlhdCI6MTQ4MTI3OTI5MH0.QIxFmbap_cDsUB5L_OxE29haev7cSe29lHZtmVTnJ3c") { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        self.signedIn(user!)
    }
```

The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.

where as when i test the same token online its working fine. 
http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/

Any help will be very helpfull.